# How do you control the Python prompt with a middle-man application?

Tags: python, statistics

How do you get a new application to stand between , like an I/O filter, the python prompt and the Python software? So that it would pass most stuff through to Python , unchanged , but some domain-specific paragraphs that the end-user types in , would be handled by a pre-parser, translated to python-legal syntax, and then given to Python? And output and error messages would be passed from Python to the user's prompt, like usual?

I'm a statistical programming language designer and my third project will be a data-cleaner, slanted to users who do not wish to be professional programmers. Python is great for some types of data preparation, but with a caveat: some types of data transformation benefit greatly from data-paragraphs, where each paragraph of code , pulls in some input datasets, does some querying/modifications, and puts the results in output datasets. ( examples of this are my first project , vilno data transformation ( http://code.google.com/p/vilno  or http://fivetimesfaster.blogspot.com ) , the SAS datastep, and the SQL SELECT statement ).

So ... something that combines Python with a data paragraph, and has a really easy learning curve, would be incredibly useful.

Robert Wilkins

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look at [this](http://docs.python.org/extending/), [this](http://fmeyer.org/en/writing-a-DSL-with-python.html) and if your DSL is going to really differ from Python, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler) and [this](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Also, I would also recommend you look into [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) as it is very easy to write domain specific languages in it. And, despite what a lot of people say, its not just for web development and ruby 1.9 speeds are comparable to python.

Then, of course, there's Lisp, but, I think I'm getting carried away :)